# Como mostrar datos de una consulta especificando los registros en java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

lo que yo quiero es que cuando se seleccione al cliente de la tabla se le muestre todas las compras que ha hecho ese cliente en un jtable y que cuando busque por ejemplo una fecha solo me aparezcan los registros de ese cliente y no de todos

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor tu pregunta debes de editarla y colocar el código del avance que llevas

Answer (score 1):

En varios proyectos en los que he trabajado he tenido que hacer esto.

1. crear objeto con todos los parámetros que existen en la base de datos como por ejemplo: `Persona(id, nombre, apellido, compra)`
2. crear una lista de objetos como `ArrayList` o `Map` para guardar el objeto "persona"
3. popular la lista haciendo un query de búsqueda `SELECT compra FROM transacciones WHERE id = "usuario"` y guardándolo en la lista con un comando como `.add()`

4.- hacer un método que muestre solo transacciones a tu gusto como `getTransaccionPorFecha(fecha)` o `getTransaccionPorPrecio()`

Espero esto te sirva jeredick. Por favor sé mas especifico en tus próximas preguntas para poder ayudarte más a detalle.